# How to find multiple centers of gravity?

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, geolocation, centroids

Say I have a number of customers in a geographical area, marked "`c`":

[image]

Each customer has a Lat/Long. I would like to find `x` number of points, in the same space, that best serve the customers, ie. they are closest to the customers.

Its easy to do when `x = 1`, because that is the geographical center of gravity, and there are a few ways to find that out. However I am struggling to think of how I would approach this problem if `x > 1`

Say `x = 2`, then I would like to know, where would I place the two points so the distances to customers are minimised, how would I even approach this problem?

I would eventually try and solve this using a programming language, so I am not after a purely mathematical formula, even though that would help.

Comment: Sorry, probably totally offtopic and maybe even a little out of line, but red Cs on a green background are really hard to read, even if you're not colorblind (no, I'm not colorblind). Is there a reason why you chose those colors?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Sorry the green seemed like a good color for land, and the red, well that was for no particular reason.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at the [K-means clustering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), which produces what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate solution. Cover area by regularly spaced points. Go through every combination of thrm by 2 ( itertools can be handy) computing total of distances to nearest of 2. Pick pair with min total.

Comment: Go through every combination by 2? Sorry I do not understand.